# What is the difference between Schedule and Optimize in Dispatcher Console in Field Service Lightning?

Tags: field-service-lightning

In the Field Service Dispatcher Console, there seems to be two ways in which we can ask the platform to schedule Service Appointments. The first is the Schedule button and the second is the Optimize hyperlink which invokes the global optimization.

What is the difference between the two apart from the fact that Optimize sends data to an external service for Optimization?

[image: FSL Schedule vs Optimize]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optimize button uses the Optimization technique explained [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/field-service-lightning-optimization/explore-optimization) to make sure your schedule is more accurate when you use Schedule.

The process of optimization is asynchronous and takes a lot of computing resources and hence its process outside Salesforce Core.

Comment: So if it is just the accuracy that differs - what is the incentive to click on Schedule for Dispatchers? I mean every business would want a more accurate schedule.

Comment: Note that it is async process and takes time to run! Hence it’s possible you can go with schedule and later optimize it!

Comment: Ah, Got it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Schedule looks at the job you're scheduling and finds the best place for it in isolation of work currently assigned. So if you selected 3 jobs and pressed schedule, it schedules them 1 at a time. Optimization looks at jobs scheduled for a given time period and will then seek to reshuffle them to find a better order to complete them - eg allowing you to get more jobs per tech per day (minimize travel) or serve customers earlier (asap) or reschedule work in jeopardy because of overruns, late starts, etc.

Both leverage schedule policy - scheduling is a job at a time, optimize is looking at scheduled jobs and finding a better way of doing them a